# How to fix bus error at pop function in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, bus-error

I'm trying to reverse a word in C with the implementation of stack. For example, If ı call the `reverseArray`function with the parameter string "Ali", then function should reverse the word and make it "ilA". The problem is when I try to Pop the value from stack, a `bus error` occurs.

Here is the `stack`struct.

```
struct stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    char *ar;
};
```

Here is my `reverseArray` function:

```
void reverseArray(char word[])
{   // Length of the given word.
    int loe = strlen(word);
    printf("%d",loe);
    struct stack* stck = createStack(loe);
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loe; i++) 
    Push(stck, word[i]); 
    
    // This is the line bus error occurs.
    for (i = 0; i < loe; i++)
    word[i] = Pop(stock);
    
}
```

Here is my Pop function:

```
char Pop(struct stack* my_stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(my_stack))
    {
        
        return 0;
    }

    return my_stack->ar[my_stack -> top--];
}
```

Here is my Push function.

```
void Push(struct stack* my_stack, char val)
{
    if (isFull(my_stack))
    {
        printf("Overflow!!!!!!");
        return;
    }
    my_stack -> top += 1;
    my_stack->ar[my_stack -> top] = val;
}
```

Here is my `isEmpty` function

```
int isEmpty(struct stack* my_stack)
{
    return my_stack -> top == -1;
}
```

and here is my `createStack`function

```
struct stack* createStack(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct stack* newStack = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    newStack -> top = -1;
    newStack -> capacity = capacity;
    newStack -> ar = malloc(newStack -> capacity * sizeof(char*));

    return newStack;
}
```

I believe the problem is in the `Pop` function. If I delete the Pop part of the code in `reverseArray` function, function works fine. Feel free to ask more information.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Please provide the missing functions and typedefs `struct stack`, `createStack`, `Push`.

Comment: Note well that `'Ali'` is not a string (it is an integer character constant).  If that's really what you are passing to your `reverseArray()` function then it's not surprising that breakage occurs.  C string literals have double quotes: `"Ali"`.

Comment: In `createStack` you are allocating much more space for the stack data than you need.  There's no reason to think that that causes your error, however.

Comment: You say the error occurs when you call `Pop()`, but the `reverseArray()` code presented never calls `Pop()`.  To provide debugging help, we need to see code that actually exhibits the bug.

Comment: If I build a program out of the functions you provided (adding an implementation of `isFull()`) in which I call `reverseArray("Ali")`, the program runs successfully, printing "3Ali" as its output.  This is what I would expect from the code currently presented.

Comment: My bad, I meant to write " not ' and I now added the Pop function into ```reverseArray```